# Simple url rewriting

Tags: nginx

I have a simple index.html page with some javascript.

On my nginx config, I would like to apply this rule :
Rewrite http://www.mywebsite.com/?l=A1B2C3 to http://www.mywebsite.com/A1B2C3

Here is my file (I got a 500 error) :

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root ...;
    index index.html;
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;

    location / {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /?l=$1 last;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: First place to look is in your error log file to see what the underlying cause is. You can set the path with error_log /var/my/log.log

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location / {

    rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /?l=$1 last;
}
```